# TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of null after installing react native splash screen in react native CLI

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

This is MainActivity.kt file

```
package com.appmovie

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.fabricEnabled
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate 
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen; 

class MainActivity : ReactActivity() {
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashScreenTheme,true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  override fun getMainComponentName(): String = "AppMovie"

  /**
   * Returns the instance of the [ReactActivityDelegate]. We use [DefaultReactActivityDelegate]
   * which allows you to enable New Architecture with a single boolean flags [fabricEnabled]
   */
  override fun createReactActivityDelegate(): ReactActivityDelegate =
      DefaultReactActivityDelegate(this, mainComponentName, fabricEnabled)
}
```

this is launch_sccren.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/launch_screen" android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is colors.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="primary_dark">#000000</color>
   <color name="status_bar_color">#191a1f</color>

</resources>
```

This is the app.js file code. I have made splash screens before but haven't encountered this problem. Help will be appreciated

```
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import AppNavigator from './src/navigation/AppNavigator';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }, [] );
  return <AppNavigator />;
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

the main issue is I have not been able to see the splash screen
and I have followed every step.

Comment: 1) Although it appears that you have configured the splash screen appropriately in your Android code, there may be a few issues in your React Native code that need to be looked at and fixed. Here are some recommendations:
First, confirm that SplashScreen.hide() is being called.
2) Verify that SplashScreen:
Examine the AndroidManifest.xml file.
Make sure your AndroidManifest.xml file's MainActivity is pointing to the right class—that is, com.appmovie.MainActivity.
3) Verify the launch_screen.xml file.
Verify that the picture @drawable/launch_screen is in the res/drawable directory